# How can I reset the _is_copy flag on a Pandas dataframe to avoid a SettingWithCopyWarning, without copying the df?

Tags: pandas, pandas-settingwithcopy-warning

I have this code:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
df2 = df[df['a'] > 2]
df2['b'] = df2['a'] * 2
```

This code raises a `SettingWithCopyWarning`. The warning is a false positive because I've assigned the result of the slice operation to another dataframe, and I intentionally only want to modify `df2` and not `df`.

To avoid this warning, I usually call `.copy()`:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
df2 = df[df['a'] > 2].copy()
df2['b'] = df2['a'] * 2
```

However, this is inefficient; `df2` is already a copy and not a view, so there's no point in creating another copy.

A more efficient way to do this is to set the `_is_copy` attribute:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
df2 = df[df['a'] > 2]
df2._is_copy = None
df2['b'] = df2['a'] * 2
```

However, this relies on the private attributes of the dataframe and isn't future-proof.

How can I reset the `_is_copy` attribute without making doing a heavyweight copy operation?

I'm using Pandas 1.5.3 and cannot easily switch to Pandas 2.0 or above.

Comment: You could try swapping the order of modification and subset. e.g. `idx = df['a'] > 2; df.loc[idx, 'b'] = df['a'] * 2; df2 = df[idx]`

Comment: @NickODell that would modify df, right? I don't want to modify df. Also, this is a simplified example; in practice the slice operation happens in a different function that I don't want to modify.

Comment: Why don't you just catch the warning?

Answer (score 0):

You can use method chaining.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3, 4]})

df2 = (df
       .query(expr="a.gt(2)")
       .assign(b=df.a * 2)
       )

print(df2)
```

Output:

```
   a  b
2  3  6
3  4  8
```